# When Do I need to set -cp or -classpath using command prompt. Please note that I am not interested in setting environment variable

Tags: java

Say A.java file is on desktop. 
Now in command prompt I will write cd C:\Users\xyz\Desktop then 
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin. 
Now since class will be on desktop then no need of setting classpath. 
I really need to understand when I need to set class path with simple example. 
**AND I AM INTERESTED IN USING COMMAND PROMPT ONLY, NOT IN ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE**. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting path variable using **path** in CMD console will set its value only for that particular CMD session only.That's what i can tell. Why are you reluctant on not using system variable?